# OpenGL screenshot Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

I have an application that uses GLSurfaceView to do some 3-D goodness in Android. I'd like the user to be able to take a screenshot. I think this snippet of code should be storing the pixel colors and storing them inside a bitmap. However, does anyone know how to access the gl10 element that the screen is using, so I can feed it into this function?

```
public static Bitmap savePixelsOnScreen(int x, int y, int width, int height, GL10 gl){
int b[]=new int[w*(y+h)];
  int bt[]=new int[w*h];
  IntBuffer ib=IntBuffer.wrap(b);
  ib.position(0);
//gl.glReadPixels(x, y, w, h, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ib);
gl.glReadPixels(x, 0, w, y+h, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ib);

for(int i=0, k=0; i<h; i++, k++)
{//remember, that OpenGL bitmap is incompatible with Android bitmap
//and so, some correction need.        
for(int j=0; j<w; j++)
{
int pix=b[i*w+j];
int pb=(pix>>16)&0xff;
int pr=(pix<<16)&0x00ff0000;
int pix1=(pix&0xff00ff00) | pr | pb;
bt[(h-k-1)*w+j]=pix1;
}
}


Bitmap sb=Bitmap.createBitmap(bt, w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
return sb;
return bitmap;
```

I had tried to do this from within the Activity that calls the GLSurfaceView:

```
EGL10 egl = (EGL10)EGLContext.getEGL(); 
GL10 gl = (GL10)egl.eglGetCurrentContext().getGL();
```

But every element of the int buffer is zero so I think this is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

put the code under draw(GL10 gl) method of your CClayer/CCNode class and also maintain boolean variable to draw it only once. Draw method will be called 60+ times per second.